# Logic to fill a column in pandas based on some conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm seeking help to find a good logic on how to add a new column to a Pandas df by applying some conditions.

Column "O" (min_played) will be created based on some conditions:

1. If a Player is not substituted (replaced), his playtime will be the value from column "G" (time)
2. If it is substituted (replaced), his playtime will be the value from column "N" (subs)
   AND the remaining time will be added to the player with which he was replaced in the same column "O" (min_played)

Example:

1. Player "**Antonio M.**" from *column "J" (name)* IS NOT replaced, *column "N" (subs)* => min_played = time (94.54 = 94.54)
2. Player "**Bowen J.**" from *column "J" (name)* IS replaced by "**Anderson F.**"
   "**Bowen J.**" min_played = 89 <*value taken from column "N" (subs)*>
   "**Anderson F.**" min_played = 94.54 <*value taken from column "G" (time)*> minus 89 <*value taken from column "N" (subs)*> => Total min_played = 5.54
   AND this value SHOULD be added to ***column "min_played" row 13***

   Why row 13: because his name is present there <***column "J" (name) row 13***>

For each round <*column "B" (tournament_type)*> I have to apply this process

[Sample Data](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmQMW9rHXUYShNpnyH9iEHcypuv_1A?e=m0Pt42)

```py
# Convert End Time to float
def convert_to_float(x):
    remove_char = lambda x: x.replace(' ','').replace(':','.')
    temp_list = remove_char(x).split('+')
    return sum([float(i) for i in temp_list])

df['time'] = df['time'].apply(convert_to_float)

# Convert Sub-Out Time to Float
def min_played(x):
    try:
        min_played = x.split(" ")[0].replace("'","")
        return convert_to_float(min_played)
    except:
        pass

df['min_played'] = df['subs'].apply(min_played)

indx = 0
for x in df['status']:
    if (x == 'line-up') & (df.loc[indx, 'subs'] is np.nan) == True:
        df.loc[indx,'min_played'] = df.loc[indx, 'time']
        
    if (x != 'line-up') & (x != 'sub') == True:
        df.loc[indx,'min_played'] = 0
    indx += 1

filtr = (df['status'] == 'line-up')
df.loc[filtr, 'sub_min_played'] = df.loc[filtr, 'time'] - df.loc[filtr, 'min_played']

filtr = (df['status'] != 'line-up') & (df['status'] != 'sub')
df.loc[filtr, 'sub_min_played'] = 0

df['name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" (C)",""))

df.to_csv('q.csv')
```

Comment: please provide the sample data and your current code in question itself and not screenshots.

Comment: all done, I have updated my post

Comment: Added my solution

Answer (score 0):

There can be few edge cases in the full data which you need to handle depending on your use case. But this should be goodd starting point.

```
df = pd.read_csv('SOSample.csv')
def convert_to_float(x):
    remove_char = lambda x: x.replace(' ','').replace(':','.')
    temp_list = remove_char(x).split('+')
    return sum([float(i) for i in temp_list])

df['time'] = df['time'].apply(convert_to_float)

def min_played(time,subs,status):
    if status == 'line-up':
        if isinstance(subs,str):
            t = subs.split("'")[0]
            #eval to handle cases like `(90+3)`
            # eval("90+3") = 93
            return eval(t)
        else:
            return time
    return np.nan
    
def sub_min_played(time,status,min_played):
    if time != min_played:
        return time-min_played
        
df['min_played'] = df.apply(lambda x: min_played(x.time,x.subs,x.status),axis=1)
df['sub_min_played'] = df.apply(lambda x: sub_min_played(x.time,x.status,x.min_played),axis=1)

df
```

**Output:**
[image]